# How can I navigate backwards in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio I can **navigate backwards** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.  This is very useful when checking out the definition of a function and then immediately going back to the code I was working on.

How can I do this in Xcode?  (I'm using version 3.1.2)

Comment: I'm using XCode 4.5, and I'd still like to know if the feature exists.  There's a "Go back" feature that's part of the solution, but it only jumps to the right file, not the right point in that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode 3.1.x is admittedly a bit weak in this respect. Happily, the navigation *@zoul* mentions (The back/forward arrows in the header bar, or ⌘⌥← and ⌘⌥→) is significantly improved in Snow Leopard, and should provide the finer-grained navigation you're hoping for. <strike>Sorry there's not an immediate solution, but hopefully it helps to know that a fix is coming...</strike>

Comment: It doesn't works in Xcode 8 (yes, this question is still actual). This combinations (⌘⌥← and ⌘⌥→) are assigned for collapsing/uncollapsing code blocks. Answer (by davsan) that proposes  ^ + ⌘ + ←  is worked for me.

Comment: This question was originally about Xcode 3. Since Xcode 4, yes, the answer from @davsan is more appropriate.

Answer (score 13):

*** Writing this if people using Xcode 4 need the answer for their versions:

In Xcode 4 preferences, it's configured to be <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (control-command-left arrow) to navigate back and <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (control-command-right arrow) to navigate forwards.

Answer (score 5):

There’s a <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> that goes back in editor history, and conversely <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> that browses forward. (Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.) It goes well with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> that switches between the header and the implementation file.

Comment: on Mac it is cmd + control + <- or ->

Comment: No, this is only part of the answer.  It's not really an editor history, it's only a file history.  Most ides preserve the point-in-file, not just the file itself.  Make some edits in different files, then move the cursor in the files, then try to use the "history" - and you'll see that it returns to the wrong place.  At least in XCode 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

There are small arrows on top left corner of editor pane in Xcode.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to navigate backwards through the code.

Comment: I selected method, jumped to definition in another file, then pressed the arrow which got me back to the original place. I'm not sure what else are you looking for?

Comment: Hi stefanB,  when I tried the arrows they would take me to/from unique files but would not take me back and forth within the same file.  So for example if one file contains a relatively large amount of code I'd like to "jump back" from a function's definition within the same file.

Comment: thanks, sometimes it's more convenient, especially using mouse.

Answer (score 2):

On Macs with multitouch trackpads, you can also use three-finger-swipe left and right to navigate through the file history.

Also re: MrDatabase's comments on stefanB's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016289/how-can-i-navigate-backwards-in-xcode/1016360#1016360),  if you've been actually jumping from definition to definition (by, for instance, holding down Command and clicking on a symbol) as opposed to just scrolling, I believe that the file history should track navigation even within the same file... perhaps that was a change in Xcode 3.1.3.

Answer (score 2):

Control + Command + Arrow keys work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the ['complete shortcut list'](http://www.1729.us/xcode/Xcode%20Shortcuts.pdf), I don't know.

You can find previous with <kbd>⇧⌘G</kbd>, but that's not really what you were after I think.

Answer (score 1):

In **Xcode 13.0.0** you can use:
(OS: Mac 11.6)

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd>

Hope this help!